# Callback function for video.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I'm using the video.js plugin. I'm using ajax to load in another bunch of videos from another page but I want to call the javascript again to perform the skinning again. Is there a callback function I can use after my ajax has finished loading in the html?

To be specific I'm after the actual function name (if there is one) that video.js has made. ie the javascript which runs to dress up the videos.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax has a success call back you may be able to use.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
         //Call back stuff
    }
});
```

There are also, error and other callbacks you can use. You can find information on [here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

If you don't have access to the ajax event, you can still bind to the success call back. [Here's](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) documentation on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually after the function name or javascript that video.js has made which then generate the skinned videos. So I'm after the javascript which runs within the success line.

Comment: What is your goal here? Why do you want to access that function?

Comment: I found the answer thanks anyway Blaine :) The answer was to wrap their code in a function, and then simply call that function when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was [here](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-video-duration#comment-501468)

```
(function(){
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    var onDurationChange = function(){
        if(video.readyState){
            //to your thing
        }
    };

    video.addEventListener('durationchange', onDurationChange);
    onDurationChange();
})();
```

Trying to do

```
videojs("myplayer").ready(function() {
    console.log(this.duration()); //0
});
```

wouldn't work.