# Add a callback on videojs m3u8 playlists requests to analyse playlists content

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, video.js

Context:
I'm using videojs inside a video wall for the 24/7 monitoring of HLS services.
Beside the video wall display, I also have a Python script which polls the services and analyses the M3U8 (primary and variant playlists) to detect errors (missing variants, stalled playlist, ....)

Goal:
I would like to optimize my set of tools and run everything within the web page, avoiding dupplication of HLS request to the CDN/origin-server (videojs + python => videojs only).

What I tried:
I know how to use videojs.hls.xhr.beforeRequest to modify the requests but haven't been able to find if there is a similar way to have a callback from videojs on each every m3u8 requests so I can analyse the M3U8 received by videojs.

Question:
Is there a way to add a callback to be called by videojs after each request to get a m3u8 ?

Thanks

Jean-Michel

Comment: looks very much similar to your issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483808/callback-function-for-video-js

Comment: Thanks @NadeemTaj
I will check that in details although I'm not proficient in Ajax (just basic Javascript skills)
I'll let you know if I make progress

Comment: Perfect. will try my best to help in resolving issue or to provide workaround.